# Dagger 2.13: controlling scope of a constructor-injected class

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger Android 2.13 and am in the process of setting up Activity-scoped dependencies.

I understand how to specify scope for dependencies declared inside a Module:

```
@Module
public class MyActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    MyActivityDataRepo provideMyActivityDataRepo() {
        return MyActivityDataRepo(); // simplified for the sake of clarity
    }
}
```

But how would I specify scope of a class added to dependencies graph via constructor injection such as below?

```
class MyActivityOtherDataRepo {

    @Inject
    MyActivityOtherDataRepo() {
    } 
}
```

Is there any way to make this class Activity Scoped for `MyActivity`?

Or will it be effectively Activity Scoped as soon as it's injected into `MyActivity` via member injection? And if so, is there a way to restrict scoping to `MyActivity` only? All I can think of to do so is to make `MyActivityOtherDataRepo` package private and place it in the same package as `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scope an element by:

- annotating the `@Provides` or `@Binds` annotated method with a scope

  ```
  @Provides
  @PerActivity
  MyActivityDataRepo provideMyActivityDataRepo() { /*...*/}
  ```
- or adding a scope annotation to the class itself with constructor injection

  ```
  @PerActivity class MyActivityOtherDataRepo {
      @Inject
      MyActivityOtherDataRepo() { /*...*/}
  }
  ```

---

It will be scoped by this scope, so any component within `@PerActivity`, as well as any subcomponents will be able to provide anything `@PerActivity` scoped.

The visibility of your class (public / package private) does not directly affect this scope, but of course you would not be able to import the class in other parts of your app.

Comment: Well you could always _not_ use constructor injection and only provide it from a method in a module, then only include this module in the single component where you want to use it. I don't see any benefits though, and you'd be introducing more unnecessary complexity.